# Is there a bash builtin that works like which but respects aliases and resolves stuff from $PATH?

Tags: bash, alias, built-in

The bash builtin `type` works well to figure out what a given command will do and how it is defined, but you cannot directly extract the file path in case the command ultimately resolves to a file. For example, to only perform a `$PATH` lookup, you can use `which`:

```
$ ls true
ls: cannot access true: No such file or directory
$ ls `which true`
/bin/true
```

Assume I had an alias:

```
alias notfalse=true
```

Then I couldn't just ask `which`, but I could ask `type`:

```
$ type notfalse
notfalse is aliased to `true'
```

But what I want is to have it resolve the alias by looking into `$PATH` (no, the various flags to `type` do not seem to work).

```
$ ls `somebuiltin notfalse`
/bin/true
```

Ignore that there is a `true` builtin (which I'm shadowing with the alias), this is just an example.

Comment: What should you get back if you define the alias as `alias csort='LC_ALL=C sort'`?

Comment: @choroba: Ideally `/usr/bin/sort`, but that'd be tricky. I was also thinking about stuff like `alias ll=ls -lha`, which ideally also would be resolved to `/bin/ls`.

Answer (score 1):

`type -P` is close to what you want. From the man page:

> The -P flag forces a PATH search for each NAME, even if it is an alias,
>       builtin, or function, and returns the name of the disk file that would
>       be executed.

For example, I have `ls` aliased to `ls -G`, and `type -P ls` returns `/bin/ls`.

However, this fails in the case of built-ins that shadow executables (like the built-in `true` shadows `/bin/true`). I'm not sure there is a way around that. It also fails for choroba's example of `csort`.

Comment: I'll mention that `type -P ls` probably works because the shell expands it to `type -P ls -G` first, and everything but the first argument is ignored.

Comment: I specifically tried `type` with all switches, including `-P` and `-p` because `builtins(7)` indicated to me that this would do what I want. It doesn't only fail in the case of built-ins that shadow executables (my original example did not). Try it out with my `notfalse` example. I have no idea why it works with your `ls` example, because bash shouldn't alias-expand the argument to `type`. Maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You may parse the output of `alias notfalse` and then use `type -P` (as already suggested by chepner).

```
getaliaswithpath() {
   alias_str="$(alias "$1")"
   if [[ -n "$alias_str" ]]; then
      alias_str="${alias_str#*\'}"
      alias_str="${alias_str%%\'*}"
      type -P "$alias_str"
   else
      type -P "$1"
   fi
}

alias notfalse=true

getaliaswithpath notfalse
```

---

Improved version of `getaliaswithpath()` (2013-09-13):

```
getaliaswithpath() {
   declare IFS alias_str exitflag substr
   exitflag=0
   alias_str="$(builtin alias "$1")"
   if [[ -n "$alias_str" ]]; then
      alias_str="${alias_str#*\'}"
      alias_str="${alias_str%%\'*}"

      # stop at first successful PATH lookup (before first | symbol)
      IFS=" "
      for substr in $alias_str; do
         [[ $exitflag -eq 1 ]] && return 1
         [[ "${substr:0:1}" == '-' ]] && continue   # skip cmd line options
         [[ "${substr//=/}" != "$substr" ]] && continue   # skip substr containing = symbol
         [[ "${substr}" == '|' ]] && { echo 'no cmd binary found' 1>&2; return 1; }  # stop at first | symbol
         [[ "${substr:0:1}" == '|' ]] && { echo 'no cmd binary found' 1>&2; return 1; }  # stop if substr begins with |

         if [[ "${substr: -1}" == '|' ]]; then   # if substr ends with | ...
            exitflag=1
            substr="${substr%?}"
         elif [[ "${substr//|/}" != "$substr" ]]; then   # if substr contains | symbol ...
            substr="${substr%%|*}"                       # ... extract first part up to first |
         fi

         #echo builtin type -P "$substr"

         builtin type -P "$substr" && return 0 
      done

   else
      builtin type -P "$1"
   fi
}


(

set -f   # disable globbing

# test cases
alias usort='LC_ALL=C sort -u | cat -n'
alias usort='LC_ALL=C sort -u| cat -n'
alias usort='LC_ALL=C sort -u |cat -n'
alias usort='LC_ALL=C sort -u|cat -n'
alias usort='LC_ALL=C sort|cat -n'

getaliaswithpath usort

)
```

Comment: That's certainly a possibility. It doesn't yet manage to strip away variables and command line options (think `alias foo='VAR=VAL bar -s'`) but it's a cool idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
ls `alias | /usr/bin/which --read-alias notfalse | tail -1`
```

By the way, I have my own aliased `which` which is this:

```
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

Comment: On what system are you? On my debian jessie, `/usr/bin/which` (symlinked to `/bin/which`) is a `sh` script that doesn't understand any option except `-a`.

Comment: Looks like yours doesn't support it. Here is the man page: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which. I'm on redhat linux by the way.

Comment: Yes, there doesn't seem to be a binary full-fledged which available from the package sources.